# Get fileName from uri on KitKat Document

Tags: android, uri

I want to get fileName from a uri... I can get a fullpath from Other apps like gallery or other third party file managers, but I can't get fileName from KitKat Document, I don't need a fullPath just the fileName with an inputStream is good for me...

Thanks

Edit: I found a piece of code that solves the issue almost, but it can't get filePath of none known types like *.exe *.vcf , ...

Here's the [source](https://github.com/iPaulPro/aFileChooser/blob/master/aFileChooser/src/com/ipaulpro/afilechooser/utils/FileUtils.java)

Answer (score 0):

If you have the absolute path of file then simpley create the object of file and use getName method

```
File f = new File(<Full Path of your file>);
```

This will return file name with extension.

ANd if you do not want extension 
then use [CommonsI/O libarary](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/download_io.cgi)

And from that library you can use

```
String fileNameWithOutExt = FilenameUtils.removeExtension(fileNameWithExt);
```

Comment: If I had the filePass already I would have the fileName... thanks but it doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: What activity u r doing which returns Uri ?

Comment: Selecting a file with `Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT` and get uri with `onActivityResult`